# BigDecimal.floatValue versus Float.valueOf

Tags: java

Has anybody ever come across this:

```
System.out.println("value of: " + Float.valueOf("3.0f")); // ok, prints 3.0
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("3.0f").floatValue()); // NumberFormatException
```

I would argue that the lack of consistency here is a bug, where BigDecimal(String) doesn't follow the same spec as Float.valueOf() (I checked the JDK doc).

I'm using a library that forces me to go through BigDecimal, but it can happen that I have to send "3.0f" there. Is there a known workaround (BigDecimal is inaccessible in a library).

Comment: `new BigDecimal(String)` doesn't expect an `f` to be in the `String`.

Comment: Ideally, one should also use [BigDecimal.valueOf("3.0")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) instead of the constructor.

Comment: As Ivan said, you can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 4):

The second example would never work since [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't mention anything concerning an `f` in the String:

> The String representation consists of an optional sign, `'+'` (`'\u002B'`) or `'-'` (`'\u002D'`), followed by a sequence of zero or more decimal digits ("the integer"), optionally followed by a fraction, optionally followed by an exponent...

A workaround could be simply stripping the `f` off of the String.  It should be valid then.

Comment: Yes. Forces me to detect and remove the "f" in my code. Annoying at least.

Answer (score 0):

BigDecimal has its own documentation. As per [BigDecimal javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29)

> this constructor is compatible with the values returned by
>   Float.toString(float) and Double.toString(double).

It doesn't mention anything about  Float.valueOf().